# How to handle negative cases in Object/Character classification of images?(i.e. if none of the given characters is detected)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN to classify a image into English alphabets and numbers. I am using labels in form of 7 bit(1/0) vectors as in the first 1/0 tells if character present and the later 6 bits represent each of the character. eg: [1,1,0,0,1,0,0] means "a" is the character, [1,0,1,1,0,0,0] means "O" is the character,etc. I am confused about what to do for cases such that no character is detected. I want my model to give [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] as the output. Will it give automatically on training with only positive examples or do I have to find negative images and put them in dataset as well? and what negative cases should I take, because there is like infinite amount of things that are not character. I know this is not that difficult question but I am new to deep learning, so pls understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put some negative samples in your dataset. It will help model to understand that not every character or every image is a English alphabet. Regarding negative samples, you should input images of not characters (cars...) and images of characters that are not in English alphabet.

Comment: What is the recommended no. of negative samples? what must be ratio of positive to negative?

Comment: There is no rule. Just add some because that way the algorithm will learn that `not-_char` category is also available to predict